# Get bitmap from ImageView

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, imageview

I have a list view which contains images and images are loaded at run time using HTTPClient. Loading is working fine. 
Now i want to get bitmap image from imageView in that listview. But when i do it gives NULLPointerException.

I am using this code to get BitMapImage.

```
Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

I don't know where is the problem.

Here is complete code

```
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("OfferListner","Favourite called");
            ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.listImage);
            Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)imageView1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
             fos = mContext.openFileOutput(imageView1.getTag().toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
             fos.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }

        }
    });
```

Comment: post your whole code?

Comment: when are you trying to get this bitmap?. May be you are trying to get it before the HTTPClient sets the image. Your code is fine.

Comment: I wait untill it shows image in list but still same problem

Comment: Solved it problem was in ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.listImage); listImage was in parent of v.

Comment: if solved then write the thorough Answer as Answer ;)